# 2D array dimentions and traversing

Tags: c#, arrays

what the method is trying to do is to, return the number of correct picks per ticket when compared to the draw, ticket variable is a 2D array.

```
 private int[] lottoMatches(int[] draw, int[][] ticket)
    {
        // TODO
        List<int> finalresult = new List<int>();
        for(int r = 0; r < ticket.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            int drw = 0, tck = 0;
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            while (drw < draw.Length && tck < ticket.GetLength(1))
            {
                if (ticket[r][tck] == draw[drw])
                {
                    result.Add(ticket[r][tck]);
                }
                else
                {
                    drw++;
                }
                if (drw == draw.Length && tck < ticket.Length)
                {
                    tck++;
                    drw = 0;
                }
            }
            finalresult.Add(result.Count);
        }
        return finalresult.ToArray();
    }
```

Index was outside the bounds of the array.' error is returned when run, ticket.GetLength(1) is identified to be the cause

Comment: The ticket array you provide to the `lottoMatches` method does not seem to have 2 dimensions, otherwise `ticket.GetLength(1)` wouldn't make problems, right?

Comment: it has 2 dimensions

Comment: Well, either your comment or the error description in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Use the debugger to verify your assumptions and to see what your program really does with regard to (but not limited to) the ticket array. ([Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger))

Comment: question wasn't stated clearly enough, problem was being able to identify the maximum column length of which I eventually figured out. Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the code

Mainly how you are getting the lengths. However, you'll find a more elegant solution using `yield`,  `IEnumerable.Sum`, `List<T>.Contains`,  and a condition operatpor

```
private static IEnumerable<int> lottoMatches(int[] draw, int[][] ticket)
{
   for (var row = 0; row < ticket.GetLength(0); row++)
      yield return draw.Sum(t => (ticket[row].Contains(t) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

**Usage**

```
foreach(var result = lottoMatches(draw,tickets))
{
    Console.WeiteLine(Result);
}
```

or

```
var results = lottoMatches(draw,tickets).ToArray();
```

The basic premise, is for every ticket, *Sum* the elements in each Ticket `row` that *Contain* the draw element `t`

***Disclaimer*** : Totally untested

Good luck

**Additional Resources**

[yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> When you use the yield keyword in a statement, you indicate that the
>   method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an iterator.
>   Using yield to define an iterator removes the need for an explicit
>   extra class (the class that holds the state for an enumeration, see
>   IEnumerator for an example) when you implement the IEnumerable and
>   IEnumerator pattern for a custom collection type.

[Enumerable.Sum Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Nullable_System_Decimal___)

> Computes the sum of a sequence of numeric values.

[List.Contains(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Determines whether an element is in the List.

[?: Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

> The conditional operator (?:), commonly known as the ternary
>   conditional operator, returns one of two values depending on the value
>   of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional
>   operator.